# Where does the phrase, "to stop on a dime" come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms, phrase-origin

I grew up hearing phrases like, "X can stop on a dime," meaning that X, presumably at the controls of some kind of vehicle, can bring that vehicle to a stop in as short a distance as the diameter of a U.S.A. 10 cent piece (a dime, a very small coin little more than a centimeter in diameter). When and where does this phrase come from? As far as I can tell, other questions on this site refer to other uses of the word dime, or they mention this phrase in passing without explaining its origin.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [When and how did we start getting “off the dime”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281340/when-and-how-did-we-start-getting-off-the-dime)?

Comment: I think it's not stopping distance (the diameter of a small coin) , rather the fact that the vehicle, horse, etc, could stop exactly where the driver or rider desires.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this came from horse-riding.  At least the earliest reference I can find suggests that stopping or turning on a small coin is likely to be from that source.

> He was such a clever horse , too: some. could turn on a sixpence as
> the saying was
>
> *All the Year Round: A Weekly Journal - Volume 71 - 1892 - Edited by Charles Dickens*
>
> [Google
> Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XNwRAAAAYAAJ&q=%22turn+on+a+sixpence%22&dq=%22turn+on+a+sixpence%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEpID0gYztAhVkRxUIHe0dCgk4FBDoATAFegQIARAC#v=snippet&q=%22turn%20on%20a%20sixpence%22&f=false)

The extraordinary feature of this, in my mind, is that the text goes on to talk about cactus. We don't have naturally-growing cactus in Britain so presumably the action takes place in America. Yet the term is still "sixpence" which was a British coin.

Comment: Yes, I'd say this is valid in spite of denominational differences.